# How to find the Big-O of this function: $log(n!)/log(n)^3$

Tags: asymptotics

The definition of Big-O is
$$u_n = O(v_n) \iff (\exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{*})\,\, (\exists N \in \mathbb{N}) \,\, n > N \implies u_n < c \, v_n$$

Based on that I am trying to find the upper bound for this function
$log(n!)/log(n)^3$.

What I've done so far is:

$log(n!) = log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n!) <= n*log(n) \implies log(n!) = O(n*logn) $

So, $log(n!)/log(n)^3 = O(n*log(n)/log(n)^3)$.

**Can we simplify this even more by saying that:** $O(n*log(n)/log(n)^3) = O(n)$ ?

Comment: Use `$\log(x)$` for $\log(x)$.

Comment: How would you simplify $\log(n)/\log(n)^3$ ?

Comment: You are writing $O(f(n))=O(g(n))$, but I think you mean to write $f(n)=O(g(n))$. You *can* ignore the $\ln(n)^3$ in the denominator, but there is really no reason to do so. There's no "right" answer when it comes to big-$O$ notation. I could say $\ln(n!)=O(n^{1000})$ but that's not very useful. Big-$O$ notation is about simplifying expressions enough that we can understand how they grow, without throwing too much away.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner oh lol my bad! Thanks

Comment: @kccu useful insights, thank you very much.